# xinetd read post data

Tags: bash, http, xinetd

I'm trying to write a simple handler for a webhook using xinetd and bash. I have the trivial case working with this config for xinetd:

```
service github-hooks
{
    port            = 61000
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    user            = ubuntu
    server          = /home/ubuntu/github-hooks.sh
}
```

and this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

now, I want to read in the post data that is being sent in the webhook so I can do something more interesting that always returning 200.

How do I do read the post data from my bash script?

I've tried:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line" >> /home/ubuntu/test
done < /dev/stdin
```

but that is not working for me.

**Edit**

Thanks to the suggestion below, I stopped `xinetd` and used `nc` to see what raw data was coming over the wire:

```
$nc -l 61000
```

and got this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: <snip>:61000
Accept: */*
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/375c44e
X-GitHub-Event: pull_request
X-GitHub-Delivery: 2dc1fb00-1c8e-11e6-9955-64afafb6ce32
content-type: application/json
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=45afd85b7d4312fa8ac4c56638e8e9699e2ddb36
Content-Length: 20558

{"action":"opened","number":116,"pull_request": <snip>
```

So, the data is being sent. Now, Knowing that there are exactly 11 lines being sent, I read exactly 11 lines:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    read line
    echo "$line" >> /home/ubuntu/test
done
```

And, I get the same output (great success :)

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: <snip>:61000
Accept: */*
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/375c44e
X-GitHub-Event: pull_request
X-GitHub-Delivery: 2dc1fb00-1c8e-11e6-9955-64afafb6ce32
content-type: application/json
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=45afd85b7d4312fa8ac4c56638e8e9699e2ddb36
Content-Length: 20558

{"action":"opened","number":116,"pull_request": <snip>
```

Maybe I should just read 9 lines then use the `Content-Length` parameter to read the rest? I still don't really understand what's going on so any information would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I never did figure out how to read while there is input but I did notice that there is a length in the header. So, I parse out the length and then read that number of characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..9}
do
  read line
done

array=(${line})
length=${array[1]}

read line
read -n ${length:0:-1} line

echo "$line" >> /home/ubuntu/test

echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

And, now I've got the post data that github is sending over.

Answer (score 0):

To read standard post data for an xinetd http request, a program just reads standard input.

I have written a bash script that reads and parses the http headers as passed in through standard input. Useful when called from xinetd. I created this as a starting point for someone that wants to create an xinetd service that can recognize HTTP REST-like calls.
https://github.com/rglaue/xinetd_bash_http_service

But essentially, reading the HTTP input (Headers and POST data) in an xinetd service looks something like this:

```
# Read HTTP Headers, line by line
# We're looking for the Content-Length HTTP header
: ${HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:=0}
while read -t 0.01 line; do
    # If the line is empty, stop reading headers
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then break; fi
    # Read each HTTP Header
    if echo "${line}" | grep -qi "^some-header:"; then
      # do something here
    elif echo "${line}" | grep -qi "^Content-Length:"; then
      HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH="$(echo "${line}"|cut -d" " -f 2-)"
    fi
done
# Next read from standard input into the HTTP_POST_DATA variable
# (This assumes the request is a POST)
while IFS= read -N $HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH -r -t 0.01 post_buffer; do
    echo "Reading in the HTTP Post Data"
    HTTP_POST_DATA="${HTTP_POST_DATA}${post_buffer}"
    if [ ${#HTTP_POST_DATA} -ge ${HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH} ]; then
      # Make sure we stop reading, since we have read enough.
      break;
    fi
done
```

Why use `IFS=`

- The `-r` flag already reads the data in without stopping at delimiters
- IFS is the Internal Field Separator used by bash to determine how words are split, and how lines are split.
- We empty `IFS` to make sure bash does not change our expected results from the raw read `read -r`.

For the `read` parameters:

- The `-t 0.01` flag defines the read timeout in seconds (0.01 sec)
- The `-r` flag reads the data in raw, which ignores the delimiters `\r\n`
- The `-N <num>` flag reads <num> characters.

Answer (score 0):

literally `cat`, or `xargs`, or `grep .` or anything else that reads from stdin.